# reliable and popular HLA imputation tools

Tags: imputation, tools

Could someone recommend me popular and reliable tools for HLA imputation?
I'm starting my master thesis project and I will infer the HLA region of 2000 sample in a case-control study; I searched for benchmarks on PubMed but I really wanted to now if someone experienced in this kind of analysis can help me
ty

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You at the very least have to specify what kind of data you are working with.

Comment: This sounds like a question that is opinion based, without a clear best answer, and an answer that is likely to change in the future. Such questions are difficult to handle  with the stackexchange format. May I suggest you try https://www.biostars.org/ ?